# How get correct type of T

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I have some code like this:

```
    Private Shared Function ReStoreFromXML(Of T)(ByVal TargetType As T, ByVal XMLpath As String) As List(Of T)

        If Not TypeSupported(TargetType) Then Return Nothing
....
        Return CType(mySerializer.Deserialize(fstream), List(Of T))
```

TargetType is, for example, MyCustomType.

TypeSupported should check if TargetType is ok. When I try something like

```
TargetType.GetType
```

Or

```
GetType(T)
```

I get only System.RuntimeType or System.Type. How can I fix this issue?

**UPD:**

For more clearly understanding what I want... also in method ReStoreFromXML I have such code:

```
 Dim mySerializer As XmlSerializer
 mySerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
```

How can I create mySerializer with argument MyCustomType?

Comment: How are you calling your `ReStoreFromXML` function? Are you passing in a `Type` instance as the first argument? If so, that would make `T` `Type`, *not* the type you're passing.

Comment: @hvd That's the problem. If you call `ReStoreFromXML(GetType(string), ...)`, then `T` will be Type/RuntimeType. If you call `ReStoreFromXML("somestring", ...)`, `T` will be `string.`

Comment: @Dominic Kexel thnx, you comment gives me right way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I call my function in such way viewsList = ReStoreFromXML(GetType(MyCustomType), XMLpath)

That's your problem.  If you call `ReStoreFromXML(GetType(string), ...)`, then `T` will be Type/RuntimeType. If you call `ReStoreFromXML("somestring", ...)`, `T` will be `string`.

So just remove the first parameter, as it's unnecessary since you already know the type by calling `GetType(T)`.

```
Private Shared Function ReStoreFromXML(Of T)(XMLpath As String) As List(Of T)
    Dim mySerializer = New XmlSerializer(GetType(T)) 
    ...
End Function

ReStoreFromXML(Of MyCustomType)(XMLpath)
```

Comment: It's not completely what I want. I need ReStoreFromXML works with some types, not only MyCustomType.

I'll make my code works in this way:
viewsList = ReStoreFromXML(New MyCustomType, XMLpath)

Comment: I don't see a problem. `ReStoreFromXML` is still generic, so can just call `ReStoreFromXML(Of WhatEverYourTypeIs)(XMLpath)`.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Thnx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The type should be the type argument to the function, not an argument of that type. (Yes, it's confusing).

This way you are stating the type twice, so a reasonable call will be:

```
ReStoreFromXML(Of String)("somestring", xmlPath)
```

Where the "somestring" is only used to check that it's indeed a string, and that's already stated in the `(Of String)` part.

You should change the signature of the method to:

```
Private Shared Function ReStoreFromXML(Of T)(ByVal XMLpath As String) As List(Of T)
    If Not TypeSupported(T) Then Return Nothing
    ...
End Function
```